# Is there a front end testing comparison tool that I can use to check for differences before and after making changes to a wordpress site?

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins, frontend, comparison

Like updating plugins which may cause something to break, before updating take a "screenshot" or "recording" using this tool of the site and take one after updated to check if anything is broken or has changed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library etc. are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do a backup of your ftp or use a special backup plug-in in wordpress. This is probably the best method to restore your site if needed.